# Copy file with specific extension with creating folder structure

Tags: c#, vb.net, powershell, batch-file, utility

I want to copy files with a specific extension (for example .config or .exe). It should create a structure of nested directories, and then insert each file into a specified place in the directory hierarchy. Ideally I would just specify a parent directory for each file and a parent directory for each directory and it would build it.

I need any existing utility or batch file or power-shell script or C#/VB .Net code to perform this activity.

Many Thanks,
Amit Lohakare

Comment: did any of these answers work for you?  If so, you should accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just simple `xcopy.exe /s /i "1\*.config" "2"` will find all .config files recursively in directory 1 and copy them to directory 2 accordingly to folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Copying a directory structure in PowerShell:

```
$source = "c:\dev"
$destination = "c:\temp\copydev"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object { $_.psIsContainer } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination } |
    ForEach-Object { $null = New-Item -ItemType Container -Path $_ -Force }
```

Copying ".config" files can be done with something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object { -not $_.psIsContainer -and ($_.Name.Contains(".config") } |
    Copy-Item -Force -Destination { $_.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($source), $destination }
```

Your question is not clear about WHERE you want to copy things, so you'll have to tailor the few lines above to your needs.